# How to intercept resources using spring interceptors or filter

Tags: spring

My config in applicationContext.xml is as follows:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lixindi.gradproject"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="login/**" location="login/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="admin/**" location="admin/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="vote/**" location="vote/"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/admin/**"/>
            <bean class="com.lixindi.gradproject.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

LoginInterceptor:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
        if (httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/login/login.html");
            System.out.println("invoked");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

There are several html files under webapp/admin which I do not want to go through DispatcherServlet. And the interceptor does not intercept requests, for example, http://localhost:8080/admin/admin.html. But I want any url including resources to be intercepted to make sure users are logged in. How could I make this work?

Thanks @Serge Ballesta.

However, it still cannot intercept resources, for example, http://localhost:8080/admin/admin.html.

web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.lixindi.gradproject.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

LoginFilter:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    System.out.println("filter");
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {

        response.sendRedirect("/login/login.html");
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

public void destroy() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors are a kind of private filters which are called by the SpringMVC machinery around the controller (or even after the rendering phase). So it makes no sense to ask for an interceptor to be called for an URL not processed by DispatcherServlet which is the entry point of that machinery.

You will have to use a plain Java-EE `Filter` here, because filters are called directly by the servlet container

Comment: thanks. But it still cannot intercept resources. Please see my updated question.